# div - section - top distance to text

Tags: html, css, distance

I can´t find the way to reduce the distance in a section (div) container, I would like the blue text to be placed closer to the top of the section (yellow box). Note this text field is actually a table of one row at the moment, but I believe this makes no difference.

```
#househeader {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;        
    background-color: yellow;       
}
```

[screenshot -  distace to top of section to reuce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU2Wy.jpg)

Comment: you need to share your code so we can help you

Comment: http://bryllupfoto.com/test/divsizeMobile.php

The code can be find in this two files

http://bryllupfoto.com/test/mystyle.txt  and file
http://bryllupfoto.com/test/divsizeMobile.txt